# Unable to call a COM parametrerized constructor from a DOT net webservice

Tags: c++, com, com-interop

I have a C++ COM component which I have added as a reference (using interop) in my webservice. My COM component has a default constructor which gets called successfully from the dot Net service.

However when I add a parameterized constructor and create an interop which is referred in the Dot Net , I do not get the parameterized constructor.

I do the following actions

1. Build the COM component
2. Register the proxy stub and the dll
3. Create the interop dll
4. Add it as a reference in the dot net webservice

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no point to adding such a constructor, it will never be called.  Review CoCreateInstance() and observe that it does not accept extra arguments.  Same for IClassFactory::CreateInstance().

Comment: @HansPassant So there is no way that I can pass an information while creating the instance of the COM component in the Web Service

Comment: COM objects don't have constructors.  (Whatever class you use to implement the object may have constructors, but that is different. You could implement your object in plain C for example, although it would be painful).  You have to use two-phase initialization to simulate a constructor, which is actually really annoying if you like the RAII paradigm.

Comment: If you want parameterized construction - no problem, introduce a factory object (with a separate interface) which will have a "create instance" method with the parameters you need.